# how to create a new object through double dref and declare it to be global?

Tags: autohotkey

```
test()
OutputDebug, % foo.baz
test (){
    bar := "foo"
    global %bar% :=  {}         ; this object is called foo
    %bar%.baz := "100"
}
```

I cant know what name this global object is going to have, as it is just a window handle number, I need to dynamically create it and set it to global so that once its known, other functions can use it.
As it is above, it will fail with this error:

```
==> This line does not contain a recognized action. Specifically: global %bar% :=  {}
```

If I remove `global` it works but then its lost and once the function exits I cant use it. `Static` is not useful, as I want other functions to use it.

Comment: This seems like a very bad pattern and I have a hard time believing this is what you actually want/need. But maybe you have some real odd edge case here. Do you want to expand on what the problem is that makes you do this?

Comment: @0x464e aaah I should have read your comment before accepting the answer. The answers solution addresses the question but I think I may engineered myself into a corner.  If it breaks again, I will ask about the issue directly then. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to encapsulate the variable as an expression.
You'll also have to remove the space between the function name and its opening parenthesis.

```
test()
OutputDebug, % foo.baz

test(){
    bar := "foo"
    global (%bar%) :=  {}         ; this object is called foo
    %bar%.baz := "100"
}
```